# How to exit a postgres docker container from a bash script

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker

I have a docker-compose.yml configured to create and add data to a database. My compose file then loads in a bash script which will run a few short tests on the data and exit 1 upon a test failing. This is working as intended, however when I want my container to exit upon all tests passing but the docker-entrypoint.sh script seems to ignore my exit 0 command. I've attempted to write a different entrypoint script which will call on the docker-entrypoint.sh in hopes that I can then exit the container, but I'm not having any luck. Is there any easy way to implement this?

Output example:

```
postgres_1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | 2020-04-06 19:29:58.511 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_1  | 2020-04-06 19:29:58.511 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2020-04-06 19:29:58.511 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2020-04-06 19:29:58.517 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2020-04-06 19:29:58.534 UTC [102] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-04-06 19:29:58 UTC
postgres_1  | 2020-04-06 19:29:58.540 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: Are there other things running in the container? The container won't exit until all the processes in it have died.

Comment: see my edit - it just says the database system is ready to accept connections. I want it to just close out upon all my tests passing.

Answer (score 1):

it's normal; entrypoint will ignore any command , to solve this you can use CDM parameter after entrypoint declaration in Dockerfile.
For example, the following snippet in Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/echo", "Hello"]
CMD ["world"]
```

when container runs as

```
docker run -it <image>
```

will produce output:

Hello world

but when container runs as

```
docker run -it <image> John
```

will result in:

Hello John

Comment: Thanks for the response. So in my instance, when would I want to exit to make sure the docker-entrypoint.sh script can exit at the right time?

Comment: for manual exit can use this method , if you want to do something after somethings should write bash script for that in entrypoint. @Polyphase29